# How to break loop if variable changes

Tags: python, loops, variables

I am running a for loop, in which the iterator loops through list of time based values.

for example this is what my list looks like

```
lst = ['00:00:01', '00:00:05', '00:00:07', '00:01:10', ... , '00:20:23']
```

I want to check if the minute part of the time data changes. If it changes then break the loop.

this is my code so far

```
time_lst = []

for time in lst:
    minute = time[3:5]

    if minute changes:
        time_lst.append(time)
        break

print(time_lst)
```

in the above program, how do I program the if condition?

I looked online but I could not find a good solution to this problem.

Comment: assign a value to "minute" before the loop starts. during loop, check the "current" minute against the "previous" assigned minute. If they match, proceed. If they mismatch, break.

Comment: Essentially, you need a variable that keeps "state" of the minute value during iteration

Comment: Understood how to do this now. thank you

Comment: @Sashaank Please, mark an answer, if your issue is resolved.

Comment: Only not sure if you want  keep tracking of times before change or after change as in `['00:00:07', '00:00:50' , '00:01:10'] ` if you want to get `00:00:50` or `00:01:10` in list @Sashaank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT**

With edited question so that it keeps changes of time between minutes

```
time_lst = []
lastMinute = lst[0][3:5] #so that it won't break on first item
for time in lst:
    minute = time[3:5]

    if minute != lastMinute: # `<>` still usable in python2, `!=` is better for compatibility between python2 and python3
        time_lst.append(time)
    lastMinute = minute

print(time_lst)
```

Comment: do you mean `!=` ?

Comment: @BlueRineS `<>` can be used still in 2.7 but yeah for python3+ it should be `!=`

Comment: Great. Maybe you should specify that in your answer

Answer (score 4):

This should work.

```
for time in lst:
    minute = time[3:5]
    if minute != lst[0][3:5]:
        break
    print minute
```

Comment: The only answer that, gives the solution to the question and it's from a new contributor

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do it by saving previous minute and compare it with new value:

```
previous_minute = lst[0][3:5]
for time in lst:
    minute = time[3:5]
    if previous_minute not minute:
        break
    previous_minute = minute
```

---

If you want to save changed times:

```
changed_times = []
previous_minute = lst[0][3:5]
for time in lst:
    minute = time[3:5]
    if previous_minute not minute:
        changed_times.append(time)
    previous_minute = minute
```

Answer (score 1):

You could keep a variable out of the loop, holding the first `minute`. Then the test is easy - you compare the new `minute` to the first one. Once they're inequal, it means the `minute` changed.

```
first_minute = lst[0][3:5]
for time in lst:
    minute = time[3:5]

    if minute != first_minute:
        break
```

However, if all you're doing in the loop is updating another list, you could use list comprehension to filter the non-minute-equal times:

```
new_list = [time in lst if time[3:5] == lst[0][3:5]]
```

You could also save `lst[0][3:5]` to a `first_minute` variable as I've done above. Another modification is to use `filter` and `lambda t: t[3:5] == lst[0][3:5]`.

NOTICE: The list comprehension solution filters *all* the list. It means if after the minute change, if the times go back to the same minute value (maybe with a different hour value?), it will include them as well - while the loop & break solution won't. Use according to your needs.

To clarify, using the first solution with `lst = ["00:00:00", "00:00:04", "00:01:00", "01:00:02"]` will result in iterating over only `["00:00:00", "00:00:04"]`, while the second will give (for the same `lst`) `["00:00:00", "00:00:04", "01:00:02"]`.

Answer (score 1):

Save the first element's minute value before starting the loop. Compare all following values with it. break if it doesn't match.

```
prev=lst[0][3:5]
for time in lst:
    if(time[3:5]!=prev):
        break
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep track of the last value.

There are several ways to accomplish this. The most straight forward is to update a variable.

```
last_value = False
for time in lst:
    minute = time[3:5]
    if not last_value:
        last_value = minute
    else:
        if minute != last_value:
            ...
            break
```